# Vuejs component reuse on navigation change - clarification sought

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In the following example, if the user navigates from `/user/foo` to `/another_page` and then to `/user/bar`, will the User component be reused?

```
const User = {
   template: '<div>User</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User }
  ]
})
```

The Vue Router manuals says ...

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.

[Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

... but it's not clear whether the component is only reused when there are no intermediary navigation steps. Is there any documentation that discusses component reuse in this kind of detail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you navigate from `/user/foo` to `/user/bar` then the component will be reused.
This is often used when displaying product page for example. **Note** that there are ways to rebuild `component` if it is needed.

If you will navigate from `/user/foo` to `/another_page` and then navigate to `/user/bar` then your `component` will be destroyed when leaving to `/another_page` and created when navigating to `/user/bar`.

To sum up:

`/user/foo -> /another_page` - component gets destroyed

`/user/foo -> /user/bar` - component will be reused